# Realloc equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Yes, another `realloc` vs. `std::vector` question. I know what you're going to say, and I agree, forget manual memory allocation, and just use a `std::vector`. Well unfortunately my professor has forbidden me to use anything from the STL for this assignment.

So yeah, I have a dynamic array of `T` and I need it to be resizable, and I can't use `std::vector`. I could return to the dark ages and do the whole thing with `malloc` and family, but if I could use `new` that would be totally awesome.

I've read plenty of threads where everyone said "no, you can't do it, use `std::vector`", but they were all posted before August 2011, and I'm hoping against hope that something might have changed since the dawn of C++11. So tell me, am I in luck, or do I have to revert to C style memory allocation?

Comment: [The homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: You can.. (god forbid) use realloc in C++ if you want.

Comment: "Well unfortunately my professor has forbidden me to use anything from the STL for this assignment." - That's no problem, `std::vector` is not in the STL, it's in the C++ standard library.

Comment: @Rapptz: You can't if you want your code to actually work.

Comment: `std::vector` is written in C++ without using `std::vector`, so it must be possible :) give it a shot. I believe what people in the threads meant to say is "no you SHOULDNT do it .."

Comment: realloc is new followed by a copy

Comment: @perreal You mean it's _malloc_ followed by a copy?

Comment: @H2CO3 are you sure? I've always been a little bit fuzzy on exactly what is and what isn't part of the STL.

Comment: I mean new as in `new int[55]`

Comment: @perreal realloc is like malloc followed by a memcpy. That is not quite the same as what C++ calls a copy.

Comment: @MichaelDorst what H2CO3 is reffering to, is the fact that STL is an old name of an outdated 3rd party library, and nowadays what is mistakenly reffered to as STL is all part of the standard library of C++. Check out [What's this STL vs. "C++ Standard Library" fight all about?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5205571) if you are interested..

Comment: @perreal you mean `malloc` followed by a copy, and sometimes it is, but if there is room, `realloc` will not copy, it will simply allocate more space.

Comment: @jogojapan whatever you're trying to tell me sounds promising, could you post an answer where you go into more detail?

Comment: @jogojapan using realloc upon non-trivially-copyable objects will result in undefined behaviour the moment a reallocation is actually required.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes True. Forget what I said.

Comment: @MichaelDorst: H2CO3 was just being a smart aleck, ignore what he said.

Comment: Don't allocators have the concept of hints? I assume that this may be used for reallocation, but I've never used it myself. However, vector (which you should just reimplement btw) is generally designed to minimise reallocation by doubling the allocation when it runs out of space.

Comment: `std::vector` *is* the `realloc` of C++. There's no other. If you cannot use it, well, that's unfortunate. Do your own allocate-and-copy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should avoid `realloc` completely anyway, because you can't move around C++ objects like that.

- Use `buf = new unsigned char[sizeof(T) * capacity]` to create a new buffer
- Cast the allocated `unsigned char *` to `T *` and use these `T`-pointers from now on
- Construct new elements via "placement `new`", as in `new (&buf[i]) T(original_copy)`
- To copy the buffer to a larger buffer, allocate the new one first, use `std::uninitialized_copy` (*not* `std::copy`), then destroy the elements in the old one using `buf[i].~T()` and deallocate the old buffer using `delete [] buf`.

All of this is assuming you don't have to worry about exception-safety, which is probably OK for the assignment.
Just be aware that in real-world code you'd have to guarantee exception safety and it's a *lot* more tedious than this.

Comment: Bad! Use `static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * cap))` to get memory, if anything. Then use placement new to stick things in there. This way, you can use normal pointer arithmetic to mark your first, last and end. I'd even say this overcomplicates things for an assignment and would just do a straight `new T[capacity]` and require default constructability.

Comment: @Xeo: I don't get it, why is `new unsigned char[]` bad, and how is `::operator new()` better? Regarding default-constructability: if he goes that route then he also needs to use `std::copy`.

Comment: The idea is that you have explicitly typed memory.

Comment: @Xeo: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't everything explicitly typed in my case too?

Comment: Not really, since you just have an `unsigned char*`. If you have a `T*` buffer, you can conveniently use three `T*` - `first`, pointing to the beginning of the buffer, `last`, pointing to one-pase-the-end of the sequence, and `end`, pointing to the end of the capacity. With those typed pointers, you can simply do pointer arithmetic, without casting or much to get wrong. But as I said, a simple `new T[N]` should suffice for a simple assignment.

Comment: @Xeo: Oh, I see why my answer confused you -- I didn't mean he should be performing the cast *every time* when accessing the elements, I just meant that he shouldn't forget to cast it before ever accessing them. He would indeed store 3 pointers which were casted from `unsigned char *` originally, but the pointers would be `T *`, which I believe is the same as what you intended. I'll clarify it in my post.

Comment: Re " you can't move around C++ objects like that", well, although std::vector can't be made to use realloc in general, it does exactly move around C++ objects like that. The problem isn't with realloc, but with the container design (which requires simple standard allocators). `realloc` would provide a very nice performance boost for a *suitable container*, no problem (greater than the implementation problem of `std::vector`, that is).

Answer (score 8):

The problem with `realloc` is that is may move the existing data to a different range of contiguous addresses.  Should it need to do so, given it's a C function the data is copied without any nod to C++ object lifetime:

- copy/move constructors aren't used
- destructors aren't invoked afterwards for the source objects

This can cause fatal consequences - for example, when the objects being moved contain pointers/references that remain pointing at addresses in the memory area being vacated.

Sadly, normal `malloc` implementations don't allow a callback hook allowing you to replace the memory-content-copying code with your own C++-safe implementation.  If you're determined you could try to find a more flexible "malloc" library, but it's unlikely to be worth the hassle and risk.

Consequently, in the general case you should use `new` to change your capacity, copy/move each object, and `delete` the originals afterwards.

If you're certain your data is simple enough that a `memcpy`-style relocation won't cause adverse consequences, then you can use `realloc` (at your own risk).