# How to insert an object in the array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have an array of pointers:

```
Hotel *hotels[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    hotels[i] = new Hotel();
```

And I want to insert an object in this array after some object with name I know:

```
cin >> tmp_name;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (hotels[i]->get_name() == tmp_name) {
    hotels[size] = new Hotel();
    size += 1;
    Hotel *tmp_hotel;
    tmp_hotel = hotels[i+1];
    hotels[i+1]->fillHotel();
    for (i = i + 2; i < size; i++) {
      hotels[i] = tmp_hotel;
      tmp_hotel = hotels[i+1];
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

What I do wrong?

UPD:
My solution:

```
cin >> tmp_name;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++, j++) {
    new_hotels[j] = hotels[i];
    if (hotels[i]->get_name() == tmp_name) {
        new_hotels[j+1]->fillHotel();
        ++j;
        system("clear");
    }
}

hotels[size] = new Hotel();
++size;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    hotels[i] = new_hotels[i];
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you have? Does the code crash (I assume so, as you increase `size` but you don't actually allocate more storage for your array), does it not give the correct result, does it not compile, ...?

Comment: This looks a lot like an almost literal translation from Java to C++. That's bad. Use `std::vector` instead of getting into trouble with naked pointers and `new`. I also have the feeling that you are using a non-standard GCC extension which allows you to specify an array's length at runtime, and that you never `delete` your objects.

Comment: Also, `hotels[i + 1]` will be out of range when `i` reaches its maximum value in the loops.

Answer (score 3):

I can see different errors in your code.

---

For example:

```
Hotel *hotels[size];
```

`size` should be a *constant expression* and something let me think this is not the case. [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the *C++* standard. In short you cannot allocate dynamic memory on the stack. The proper initialization should be:

```
Hotel* hotels = new Hotel*[size];
```

---

The line in the loop:

```
hotels[size] = new Hotel();
```

you're actually accessing out of bounds of your array: `size` index is some memory is not included in your array and this will produce an *undefined behaviour*.

---

Another strange line is the following:

```
size += 1;
```

Despite the fact that confirms `size` is not a constant, you cannot increase your size of vector simply changing that variable. You're actually just changing a variable `size`, but the allocated memory for your array will be the same.

---

## How resolve?

In order in increase (or change) the size of an array, the solution is almost always to create a *new* array, copy the old one. In your case that solution is pretty reasonable because you should copy just pointers and not entire objects.

There are a lots of question on S.O. where this topic is, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061021/realloc-equivalent-in-c).

Despite of that, I *strongly* suggest you to use the most practical alternative, that is to use a *real C++ code*.

The most efficient class is `std::vector` which is a *C++* way to handle dynamic array.

Finally, you should also consider the `std::unique_ptr<T>` class to handle dynamic memory and pointers.

The final solution will be a class:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Hotel>> hotels;
```

Comment: I'd say the final solution should be `std::vector<Hotel>`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I cannot know which obscure reasons are behind the fact he want to use pointers. Since the code level, I bet the simplest solution will be the "final" solution. Anyway I propose `std::unique_ptr` only to propose something more comparable with his code!